# A non-serializable value was detected in an action (redux-toolkit)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

In the payload of the action in the store, I store the downloaded file with the File type, which will then pass verification in the saga

```
  const form = new FormData();
 
   if (privateKey && privateKey instanceof Blob) {
     const blob = new Blob([privateKey], { type: 'multipart/form-data' });
     form.append('privateKey', blob);
```

and then send to backend

every time after downloading a file there is an error in the console

[image]

How can I fix it?
disabling the serializable-check - for me it's not good idea

Comment: @DiegoD
i can't save file in another place instead of redux store because the request is called from the saga and it is only possible to call the request separately without the saga

Comment: What about custom middleware to catch this action and serialize file by hand there or place it somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

You certainly don't want to completely disable the serializability check, but you can configure the [serializability middleware](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/serializabilityMiddleware) to ignore specific actions (*among other things*).

```js
const store = configureStore({
  ...
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [
          // the action with non-serializable payload
          // e.g. "actionWithFilePayload"
        ],
      },
    }),
});
```

You may also need to ignore any non-serializable state that is stored.

```js
const store = configureStore({
  ...
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: ["actionWithFilePayload"],
        ignoredPaths: ["stateWithFile"],
      },
    }),
});
```